# Choose formats in sscanf in c

Tags: c, string, tokenize, scanf

I am trying to parse a string `Connected to a:b:c:d completed (reauth) id=5` using `sscanf()` in c language.

My format string is `Connected to %s completed %s id=%s`. But In some cases my string is `Connected to a:b:c:d completed id=5`. I am not getting that `reauth` part.

I am able to do using two `sscanf()` calls. But I need to do using a single `sscanf()` call. Is there a way to choose formats based on some condition in `sscanf()` ?

Sample code which I am trying use

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
        char* string="Connected to a:b:c:d completed (auth) id=3";
        char* fmt = "Connected to %s completed id=%d";
        char b[60]={0};
        int id = -1;

        sscanf(string, fmt, b, &id);

        printf("Auth :: %s :: id :: %d\n", b, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   char* string1="Connected to a:b:c:d1 completed id=1";
   char* string2="Connected to a:b:c:d2 completed (auth) id=3";

   char* fmt = "Connected to %s %*[^=]=%d";
   char b[60]={0};
   int id = -1;

   n=sscanf(string1, fmt, b, &id);
   printf("Auth :: %s :: id :: %d - %d\n", b, id,n);

   n=sscanf(string2, fmt, b, &id);
   printf("Auth :: %s :: id :: %d - %d\n", b, id,n);
}
```

Where:

- `%[^=]`  will consume a non empty string of non "=" chars
- `%*...`  will discard the correspondent group (skip it)

As said before we should analyse the sscanf return value `if(sscanf ...==2)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Check the return value of the [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) with the first *format* string. If it does not equal the expected number, use the other format string for `sscanf()`.

P.S. - I assume you have *only* two formats, can appear in a *either-or* fashion.

---

EDIT:

If you want a more flexible, robust and *sleek* way to do so and if you are able to *drop* the usage of `sscanf()`, you can make use of [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to *tokenize* your string based on certain *delimters* and get the required values out of the input string.

Comment: Yes, we can do by checking returning value. Its working. But I need a single format for parsing both these strings. Can this be done ?

Comment: @KrishnaM I don't have a clear idea what you're trying to mean by _single format_, but I have updated my asnwer, see if that helps.,